# Extract a part of a string using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to extract a part of a string using ansible.

my variable is :
p_code: "apXXXXX"

I want to extract only the XXXXX value.

Thank u.

Comment: `p_code[2:]` would give you everything after the first two characters.

Comment: yes this is in Python, how can i write it in Ansible ?

Comment: That is how you would write it in ansible. You can use most Python expression syntax when evaluating Ansible variables.

Comment: can i do that :
extracted_var: "{{ p_code }}[2:]"

Comment: Your variable expressions need to be *inside* the `{{...}}` template markers. So, `{{ p_code[2:] }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ansible is based on Python you can just use [Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/6771046).

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    p_code: "ap12345"

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ p_code[2:] }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '12345'
```

Comment: Thank you @u880d